# Wrong way of exporting perl functions from a module

Tags: perl, module

I have a very small module and I am having trouble with exporting the functions from it.
Take the function `GetVar()` if I call it using `TestMod::GetVar()` It will work fine, however when I call `GetVar()` from the script in which the module is imported I get an error (listed below). I am 99% sure that I have not exported the function `GetVar()` correctly, however I can not find my mistake.

Module source:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
package TestMod;
our (@ISA, @EXPORT, $VERSION);

use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(&GetVar);
$VERSION = 0.01;


sub GetVar()
{
    return "something";
}

1;
```

Script source:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use lib "/home/user1221/projects/";
use module;

print "Version: $TestMod::VERSION";
my $a = GetVar(); #should work but doesn't
print "$a\n";
```

Error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::GetVar called at /home/user1221/projects/module_use.pl line 8.
```

Comment: See [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)

Comment: change the 'use module;' statement to 'use module (GetVar);'

Comment: This is not allowed while strict is used.

Comment: Local identifiers should consist only of lower-case alphanumerics plus underscore: capitals are reserved for global identifiers like package names. And you should *never* use subroutine prototypes, like `sub GetVar()`. It is a very advanced feature and almost certainly doesn't do what you want. `sub get_var { "something" }` is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use module;` in your script is exact equivalent of

```
BEGIN { require module; module->import(); }
```

but since you don't have `module` package nothing is imported.

What you need is

```
BEGIN { require module; TestMod->import(); }
```

or make sure your module file names follow package names.

Comment: I had not (and would have not) considered that the names of the file and module must be the same. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Bloodcount: It is *vital* that the package name and the file name match. In the case of multi-part package names like `My::Special::Package`, the module must be in a file `My/Special/Package.pm` within one of the directories in `@INC`, as described in [Perl Modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules)